# How to change orientation of xml "layout" area in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, orientation

The xml files that contains the Activity layouts can be rendered by Eclipse.

How do I get that Eclipse screen area to have vertical orientation, not horizontal (inside Eclipse - it correctly shows as vertical in the emulator)?

Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's one of the dropdowns along the top of the layout preview window in Eclipse.  I don't have access to it right now, but I think it's labeled something like "orientation".